# Select a div using another class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html code which has two div parents inside it with class "main" and "chat". There is another div in first parent with class="menu"

When user clicks on menu, it will add "open" class to the div. Now i want to hide "chat" when menu is open.

And i know  this if i want to select a class, it must be inside of that div. Is there any solution (with css or js) to select another div which is outside of that class?

And i don't have access to html code of "chat" section because it's loading from a third-party website.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>

<div class="main">

<div class="menu">
by click it will add "open" to the "menu" class
</div>

</div>

<div class="chat">
</div>

</body>
```

and this is what i want to do (but i know that doesn't work in this way):

```
.menu.open .chat {display:none;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `.chat` is not inside `.menu`. Or you are missing a starting `<div>` after `<div class="menu">`

Comment: yes `chat` is not in `menu` and this is my problem. I want to select a class which is not inside a div

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".menu").on("click", function() {
  $(".menu").addClass("open");
  $(".chat").hide();
});
```

```css
.open {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="menu">
      by click it will add "open" to the "menu" class
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat">
    Chat Div
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sample:

JS:

```
function Open(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0].classList.add("open");
    document.getElementsByClassName("chat")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="menu" onclick="Open()">
             by click it will add "open" to the "menu" class
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle()` and `toggleClass()` in click event

```js
$(".menu").on("click", function() {
  $(".menu").toggleClass("open");
  $(".chat").toggle()
});
```

```css
.open{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="menu">
      by click it will add "open" to the "menu" class
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat">
    Chat Div
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you add a class to `main` as well (or only `main`, and not `menu`). Suppose you decide to add class `menu-opened` to `main`. Now you should be able to achieve desired results using the css code:

`.main.menu-opened~.chat {display:none;}`

The `~` is used to select every `.chat` element proceeded by `.main.menu-opened` element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

**Vanilla JS:** (https://codepen.io/cssjs/pen/EMMPjV)

```
var btnMenu = document.querySelector('.menu')
var boxChat = document.querySelector('.chat')

btnMenu.onclick = handleMenu

function handleMenu(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()

  if (!btnMenu.classList.contains('open')) {
    btnMenu.classList.add('open')
    boxChat.classList.add('open')
  } else {
    btnMenu.classList.remove('open')
    boxChat.classList.remove('open')
  }
}
```

**jQuery:** (https://codepen.io/cssjs/pen/eXXZEG)

```
var btnMenu = $('.menu')
var boxChat = $('.chat')

$(btnMenu).on('click', function() {
    $(btnMenu).toggleClass('open')
    $(boxChat).toggleClass('open')
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class='main'>
        <a href="#menu" title="Menu" class='menu'>Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div class='chat'>
      <div>Some chat content.</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.chat {
  display: none
}
.menu.open {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.chat.open {
  display: block
}
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Working code as you want..But I have added "open" class on main in-spite of menu.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.menu').on('click', function(){
    $('.main').toggleClass('open');
   })
  });
```

```css
.main.open + .chat{
   display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="menu">
   by click it will add "open" to the "menu" class
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="chat">
  chat data
 </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```